# Is there a way to update php-json with brew?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, homebrew

I want to run a local project with elasticsearch composer vendor package. When I tried to install it via composer I got the following error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^5.1 -> satisfiable by elasticsearch/elasticsearch[v5.1.0].
- elasticsearch/elasticsearch v5.1.0 requires ext-json >=1.3.7 -> the requested PHP extension json has the wrong version (1.2.1) installed.
```

So I have installed PHP via brew because I need multiple PHP versions. How can I update these libraries? `brew search "json"` and `"php-json"` find nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: brew install OSX software and libraries. Composer installs PHP libraries. You have a Composer issue, not a brew issue. Fix your `composer.json` file in your project space to point to the right version of the PHP library 'ext-json'

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the version 2.2 of the library .

composer require elasticsearch/elasticsearch:2.*

Comment: Yes but how can i select the version in brew?